# TKinter show/hide canvas.line with Checkbutton

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

So i was trying to code for a project but i wasn't able to make any progress with this for a day so i decided to ask:
My goal is to have a checkbox (doesnt necessarily have to be checked at the start) that if checked shows a red line, but if unchecked the redline disappears (that's where i struggle). I have managed to make the redline appear with the button checked but afterwards if I uncheck, nothing happens and the redline remains. This is my latest try:

```
from tkinter import *
app = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(app, width=400, height=600)
canvas.pack()
redline = canvas.create_line(0, 100, 200, 50, fill="red")
def click(canvas=redline, *event):
       if var.get():
       redline
       else:canvas.delete(redline)
var = IntVar()
check = Checkbutton(app, text = "Redline", variable=var, command=click)
check.pack()
check.toggle()
app.mainloop()
```

Im grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: You have indentation problems in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`command=` expects function which doesn't get arguments.

You have to create line again.

```
from tkinter import *

# --- functions ---

def click():
    global redline

    if not var.get():
        canvas.delete(redline)
    else:
        redline = canvas.create_line(0, 100, 200, 50, fill="red")

# --- main ---

app = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(app, width=400, height=600)
canvas.pack()

redline = canvas.create_line(0, 100, 200, 50, fill="red")

var = IntVar()
check = Checkbutton(app, text = "Redline", variable=var, command=click)
check.pack()
check.toggle()

app.mainloop()
```